# cut html content and keep the format?

Tags: php

```
$str = "<div>blahblahblah<b>foofoo</b><i>barbar</i></div>";
```

I separate two part

```
1-presentation_text
2-full content when click on read more.

  $presentation  = substr($str,0,23);
 <div>blahblahblah<b>foo
  $detail = substr($str,23); 
  foo</b><i>barbar</i></div>
```

How Can I keep  the format when it display in presentation block and detail block?
I mean

in presentation block should be:

blahblahblah**foo**  /* foo have bold here*/

in detail block

**foo***barbar* /* foo have bold too*/

Comment: This question is really unclear at the moment.

Comment: I updated.Do you get the idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Much easier to do it client-side:

CSS

```
.presentation {
    width: 200px;
    height: 20px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.detail {
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
}
```

Javascript

```
$(function(){
    $('.presentation').live('click', function(){
        $(this).attr('class', 'detail');
    });

    $('.detail').live('click', function(){
        $(this).attr('class', 'presentation');
    });
});
```

HTML

```
<div class="presentation">
    <div>blahblahblah<b>foofoo</b><i>barbar</i></div>
</div>
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/fznWf/1/